# Story / Myth / Legend with most film adaptations?

Tags: adaptation, most-appearances

There are a [large number of adaptations of Robin Hood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_and_television_series_featuring_Robin_Hood), with (I think) at least 40 being films. Speaking of full-length feature films only (no TV, shorts, etc), is the Robin Hood myth the most adapted story in history, or is there one with more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What is the most remade movie story?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/16605/49)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson That's remakes not adaptations.

Comment: Seems to amount to pretty much the same thing, though.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson If you think they are the same thing, then you should not have different tags for each one. I don't think they are the same thing because one presumes a predecessor movie, but the other is something based on a book or myth, not another movie. Robin Hood is not a remake, it is an adaptation because it based on a pre-modern legend, not a movie.

Comment: Sherlock Holmes may be one more than Robin Hood, and stories from Bible may have a place for this I think.(based on Jesus/Christ). *A Christmas Carol* is another one but I thnk its twenty something

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to [Wikipedia's list of movies and TV shows featuring Robin Hood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_and_television_series_featuring_Robin_Hood).

I think that there are fewer than 50 theatrical movies on the list.

I have often read that Sherlock Holmes is the most often filmed character.

> It has been estimated that Sherlock Holmes is the most prolific screen character in the history of cinema.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptations_of_Sherlock_Holmes#Film

Redmond, Christopher (1993). A Sherlock Holmes Handbook. Toronto: Dundern Press. p. 164. ISBN 978-1-55488-446-9.

And:

> Sherlock Holmes is the most portrayed literary character in stage, film, and television history, having appeared on stage and screen 254 times as of 2012.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_actors_who_have_played_Sherlock_Holmes

I think that the list lists 77 Sherlock Holmes theatrical movies.

So I am inclined to believe that there are more Sherlock Holmes theatrical movies than Robin Hood theatrical movies.